# find and modify obejct in mlab collection by _id with nodejs

Tags: node.js, mlab

i am posting an object to update the current one. Searching by id and replacing it. For some reason i don't get errors but the mlab object is not updated. Am i missing something?

```
app.post("/api/updateCheck", function (req, res) {
console.log('updating', req.body);
conn.collection("checks").findAndModify({
_id: req.body._id
},  {$set: req.body}, {}, function(err,doc) {
if (err) { console.log(err) }
else { console.log("Updated"); }
});  
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it. updateOne seems to work. I am posting a check object and retrieving id from it to search the collection and update content accordingly.

```
// modify content
app.post("api/updateCheck", function(req, res) {
console.log("updating", req.body);

    conn.collection("checks").updateOne(
    {
        _id: new ObjectId(req.body._id)
    },
    {
        $set: {

            content: req.body.content
        }
    },
    function(err, doc) { 
        if (err) {
            console.log("error", err);
        } else {
            console.log('success', doc.modifiedCount);
            console.log('??', doc.matchedCounted);
            res.status(200).json(res.body);
        }
    }
    );
    });
```